# Need CSS to set current-menu-item in a sprite menu using li:children

Tags: wordpress, sprite, menuitem, children

There are 7 menu items in this sprite menu. Is is possible use CSS to assign the hover image to the current-menu-item in a WordPress site?

Example of the css for the fourth child menu item:

```
#second-menu li:first-child + li + li + li   a{ background: url(images/kmdd_menu2.png) no-repeat -269px 0px; display:block; height:110px; width:91px; margin-right: 40px; text-indent: -9999px;}

#second-menu li:first-child + li + li + li   a:hover { background: url(images/kmdd_menu2.png) no-repeat -269px -111px; display:block; height:110px; width:91px; margin-right: 40px; text-indent: -9999px;}
```

Tried this: `second-menu li.current-menu-item:first-child + li + li + li a {`
to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

This will target the fourth menu item in a sub menu

```
ul#second-menu>li.current-menu-item>ul>li:nth-child(4) a:hover{}
```